# javascript column sort for currency on html table

Tags: javascript, html

I have the code below that I'm using to sort the columns on an html table. It works fine for sorting alphabetically. It also works for sorting when the numbers are single digit.

When I try to sort a column that contains a currency then the sort function doesn't sort the numbers in the correct order.

What would I need to change so it would sort the currency column correctly?

```js
function sortTable(n) {
  var table, rows, switching, i, x, y, shouldSwitch, dir, switchcount = 0;
  table = document.getElementById("CarTable");
  switching = true;

  dir = "asc";

  while (switching) {

    switching = false;
    rows = table.getElementsByTagName("TR");

    for (i = 1; i < (rows.length - 1); i++) {

      shouldSwitch = false;

      x = rows[i].getElementsByTagName("TD")[n];
      y = rows[i + 1].getElementsByTagName("TD")[n];

      if (dir == "asc") {
        if (x.innerHTML.toLowerCase() > y.innerHTML.toLowerCase()) {

          shouldSwitch= true;
          break;
        }
      } else if (dir == "desc") {
        if (x.innerHTML.toLowerCase() < y.innerHTML.toLowerCase()) {

          shouldSwitch= true;
          break;
        }
      }
    }
    if (shouldSwitch) {

      rows[i].parentNode.insertBefore(rows[i + 1], rows[i]);
      switching = true;

      switchcount ++;
    } else {

      if (switchcount == 0 && dir == "asc") {
        dir = "desc";
        switching = true;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```css
table {
    border-spacing: 0;
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
}

th {
    cursor: pointer;
}

th, td {
    text-align: left;
    padding: 16px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #f2f2f2
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>


<table id="CarTable">
  <tr>

    <th onclick="sortTable(0)">Name</th>
    <th onclick="sortTable(1)">Amount1</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Mustang</td>
    <td>$2,000.00</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Charger</td>
    <td>$300.00</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Corvette</td>
    <td>$225.00</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Firebird</td>
    <td>$2,600.00</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>GTO</td>
    <td>$260.00</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Camaro</td>
    <td>$1,000.22</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Barracuda</td>
    <td>$52.00</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Impala</td>
    <td>$25.00</td>
  </tr>
</table>



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Should this be done in native JavaScript or are you able to leverage an API like jQuery (one of the most popular JavaScript libraries ever)?

Comment: Also, your code compares the lexicographic order of **strings**, not numbers. You can, for string like this: `var money = '$300.00'`, extract its value into a `Number` like this: `var moneyAmount = Number(money.substring(1))`, or even better: `var moneyAmount = Number(money.substring(money.indexOf('$')).trim())` . The former just extracts from the second character and converts that to number, whereas the latter finds the `'$'`, extracts from the character after, trims surrounding whitespace, and then converts to number.

Comment: Last but not least, I notice your code simply does linear walk through the list of `<tr>`s containing data, and swaps `<tr>` at index `k` with `<tr>` at index `k+1`, for k integer between 1 and `rows.length - 2`, inclusive. This does **not** sort a list. You should look into either the different sorting algorithms (bubble, insertion, quick, heap, ... ), or leverage the `Array.prototype.sort()` method to do the sorting for you, based on criteria. 

More information on the latter: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added the next if to extraxt the values depending on the column

```
   if (n == 0) {
        xText = x.innerHTML.toLowerCase();
        yText = y.innerHTML.toLowerCase();
      } else {
        xText = parseFloat(x.innerHTML.split('$')[1].replace(/,/g, ''));
        yText = parseFloat(y.innerHTML.split('$')[1].replace(/,/g, ''));
      }
```

I also replace `x.innerHTML.toLowerCase()` and `y.innerHTML.toLowerCase()` for `xText` and `yText` this to make an easy change of values depending on the column

Finishing with `parseFloat(y.innerHTML.split('$')[1].replace(/,/g, ''));` to extract the float value and delete both the $ sign and the commas

Hope this is what you were looking for :)

```js
function sortTable(n) {
  var table, rows, switching, i, x, y, shouldSwitch, dir, switchcount = 0;
  table = document.getElementById("CarTable");
  switching = true;

  dir = "asc";

  while (switching) {

    switching = false;
    rows = table.getElementsByTagName("TR");

    for (i = 1; i < (rows.length - 1); i++) {

      shouldSwitch = false;

      x = rows[i].getElementsByTagName("TD")[n];
      y = rows[i + 1].getElementsByTagName("TD")[n];


      if (n == 0) {
        xText = x.innerHTML.toLowerCase();
        yText = y.innerHTML.toLowerCase();
      } else {
        xText = parseFloat(x.innerHTML.split('$')[1].replace(/,/g, ''));
        yText = parseFloat(y.innerHTML.split('$')[1].replace(/,/g, ''));
      }

      if (dir == "asc") {
        if (xText > yText) {
          shouldSwitch = true;
          break;
        }
      } else if (dir == "desc") {
        if (xText < yText) {
          shouldSwitch = true;
          break;
        }
      }
    }
    if (shouldSwitch) {

      rows[i].parentNode.insertBefore(rows[i + 1], rows[i]);
      switching = true;

      switchcount++;
    } else {

      if (switchcount == 0 && dir == "asc") {
        dir = "desc";
        switching = true;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```css
table {
  border-spacing: 0;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}

th {
  cursor: pointer;
}

th,
td {
  text-align: left;
  padding: 16px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #f2f2f2
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>

</head>

<body>


  <table id="CarTable">
    <tr>

      <th onclick="sortTable(0)">Name</th>
      <th onclick="sortTable(1)">Amount1</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Mustang</td>
      <td>$2,000.00</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Charger</td>
      <td>$300.00</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Corvette</td>
      <td>$225.00</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Firebird</td>
      <td>$2,600.00</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>GTO</td>
      <td>$260.00</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Camaro</td>
      <td>$1,000.22</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Barracuda</td>
      <td>$52.00</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Impala</td>
      <td>$25.00</td>
    </tr>
  </table>



</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You call that sorted?!

Comment: @MikeWarren pliss click on the ``Amount1`` header. I didnt design this table and you should check the code before adding a rude comment :)

Comment: I missed the `onclick`. My bad.

Comment: @MikeWarren no worrys. Did you like the solution? Or should i change something?

Comment: The solution is nice in that it works while minimizing changes. I just didn't know the use case for the sorting. I do have solution that I believe is more concise, but I don't know if the person asking the question would make use of it.

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is replace the comparing logic. I took the liberty of changing this part in your code with a function that accepts a `mode` parameter. You can extend it easily.

```js
function sortTable(n,mode) {
  var table, rows, switching, i, x, y, shouldSwitch, dir, switchcount = 0;
  table = document.getElementById("CarTable");
  switching = true;

  dir = "asc";

  while (switching) {

    switching = false;
    rows = table.getElementsByTagName("TR");

    for (i = 1; i < (rows.length - 1); i++) {

      shouldSwitch = false;

      x = rows[i].getElementsByTagName("TD")[n];
      y = rows[i + 1].getElementsByTagName("TD")[n];

      if (dir == "asc") {
        if (compareValues(x.innerHTML,y.innerHTML,mode)==1) {

          shouldSwitch= true;
          break;
        }
      } else if (dir == "desc") {
        if (compareValues(x.innerHTML,y.innerHTML,mode)==-1) {

          shouldSwitch= true;
          break;
        }
      }
    }
    if (shouldSwitch) {

      rows[i].parentNode.insertBefore(rows[i + 1], rows[i]);
      switching = true;

      switchcount ++;
    } else {

      if (switchcount == 0 && dir == "asc") {
        dir = "desc";
        switching = true;
      }
    }
  }
}

function compareValues(x,y,mode){
  x = parseValue(x,mode)
  y = parseValue(y,mode)
  if(x<y)
    return -1
  if(x>y)
    return 1
  return 0
}

function parseValue(val,mode){
  switch(mode){
    case 'alphabet':
      return val.toLowerCase()
    break
    case 'currency':
      return parseFloat(val.slice(1).replace(',',''))
    return
  }
}
```

```css
table {
    border-spacing: 0;
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
}

th {
    cursor: pointer;
}

th, td {
    text-align: left;
    padding: 16px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #f2f2f2
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>


<table id="CarTable">
  <tr>

    <th onclick="sortTable(0,'alphabet')">Name</th>
    <th onclick="sortTable(1,'currency')">Amount1</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Mustang</td>
    <td>$2,000.00</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Charger</td>
    <td>$300.00</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Corvette</td>
    <td>$225.00</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Firebird</td>
    <td>$2,600.00</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>GTO</td>
    <td>$260.00</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Camaro</td>
    <td>$1,000.22</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Barracuda</td>
    <td>$52.00</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Impala</td>
    <td>$25.00</td>
  </tr>
</table>



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Perfect - the fix works great for columns that are either currency OR alphabetic except my currency balance column also has some rows with text "Not Available" in them - so unless we change the text to $0.00 the fixed sort still doesn't work?   

Anyone got any suggestions?